# Multiple instances of Postfix

Tags: postfix

How can we create Multiple instances of Postfix, I am using Virtualmin. Please provide me complete step wise step tutorial.

Comment: Ok, but only if you make me a sandwich first. :)

Comment: should I mail it you, your mailing address please

Answer (score 2):

Postfix has multiple_instance variables as well as the `postmulti` command all there to help you manage multiple instances on the same host. Virtualmin, however, [does not help you with multiple instances](https://www.virtualmin.com/node/7915). That is beyond the intent of Virtualmin.

You will need to install and manage multiple instances of postfix apart from Virtualmin's interface, which may cause problems with Virtualmin itself. Some control panels are very possessive of the host server and will, upon patching, erase configurations and files that it does not recognize.

Comment: Please send me step wise step tutorial to configure multipal instance.